# Cleaning oil spill on a concrete floor

Tags: cleaning, home, cement

My house has finished concrete floors. My husband had put a chainsaw on the floor and it made an oil stain that I haven't been able to get up. What can I use to get the oil stain out?

Comment: You're asking to get the stain out, but another solution is to cover it with a rug or a piece of furniture so you don't have to see it. You could do this after using an oil absorbant, as Paparazzi suggested, if there is any lingering discoloration.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an absorbent such as oil-dri
Kitty litter is a decent absorbent

And over time it will evaporate

Answer (score 0):

You could do what I do with oil spills in my garage by taking a match with a long stick and burning away the unwanted residue. However, do that with caution and ensure that you will not light anything else on fire while you are cleaning.

Comment: The floor I'm talking about is a finished floor in my house.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how applicable this solution is to finished concrete (It depends on how polished your floor is I suppose), but an old solution can be found in this video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fPnmJItZVUE

Essentially, you take oil dry and spread it out over the stain, then you start to grind the absorbent into the concrete. In the video the guy used a brick, but I've always just put on my mowing shoes and went to town with my legs. In hindsight,  brick sounds easier, but then again, it may depend on how polished your floors are.

Answer (score 0):

If you know someone working at a gaz station you could ask them some of their absorbent. You might also find this sort of thing in hardware shops... I always found it looked it paperish sand. This will suck up most of the spill in no time. Once you have have removed everything (do not use a vacuum, this could set it on fire), use dish soap to clean the rest.

Comment: As a side note, I found out that wiki hints on dish washing liquid being used to clean oil-affected birds... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dishwashing_liquid

Answer (score 0):

Cover oil spill with oil dry evenly then pour small amount of gasoline over stain . Must be well ventilated.  Let dry overnight , sweep up oil dry. Concrete will be chalky white.